# Show notification after removing an item from the list in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of items with a delete buttons. When delete button is clicked it removes it from the list.

[image: Initial list]

But after clicking a delete button I would like to replace the deleted item with a message "Delete Complete".

[image: After removing item from the list]

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want the 'Delete Complete' to always stay on the page until the page / data is refreshed ?

Comment: one way would be leave item in array, add a `deleted` property to it and use directive or `ng-class` or `ng-if` to change display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this sample... 
It will remove the delete red flag after 3 seconds...

http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/U3pVM/18175/

```
<div class="field" ng-app="App">
    <table ng-controller="Controller">
        <tr ng-repeat="item in table">
            <td ng-class="item.style" ng-class="item.style">{{item.name}}</td>
            <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="delete(item, $index)">Delete</a></td> 
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

JS

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);
App.controller('Controller', function($scope, $timeout){
    $scope.table = [
        {name : 'Dan', deleted:false},
        {name : 'Orlando'},
        {name : 'Dany'}
   ];

    $scope.delete = function(item, index){
        item.deleted = true;
        item.style = 'deleted';

        function destroy() {
        $scope.table.splice(index, 1)
        }

        $timeout(function(){destroy();}, 3000);
    }
});
```

CSS

```
body{
    font-family:arial;
}
a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:red;
}

table{
width:300px;
}

td{
    border:thin solid #CCC;
    padding:10px;

}

tr{
 position:relative   
     width:300px;
}

.deleted:after{
    content:'DELETED';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:red;
    width:300px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:40px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/U3pVM/18175/

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for- Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. Assuming that the data is bind in ng-repeat with expression,

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="var in data">
 <td data-ng-show="!data.isDeleted">{{var.Column1}}</td>
 <td data-ng-show="data.isDeleted">Delete Complete</td>
</tr>
```

So you need to add one more property in your json data.